# Sorting displayed information on a page

Tags: html, css

I've been racking my brain on this for a week and I need some other development brains for help.   I'm not looking for code, just some feedback with direction.

We have pages that have a 10 or so groups, with 10 or so fields within each group.   Our requirement is to have the ability for a user to sort groups and to sort fields within each group as well as hide groups and/or fields, while keeping this mobile compliant.   I might just be over thinking this, but this requirement seems a like a maintenance nightmare.

Today, this is a demo within ASP.NET/C#, but we will be going to Java in the near future.  I'm attempting to figure out how this would work on the HTML5/CSS3 side, no matter the back-end technology.   I've been developing for 25 years and this is boggling my mind.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest I can come up with is to use `flexbox` and its `order` property

```css
.container,
.groups {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
.groups:nth-child(2) {
  order: -1;                /*  default is 0  */
  background: lightgray;
}
.groups:nth-child(2) .fields:nth-child(3) {
  order:  1;                /*  default is 0  */
  background: lightblue;
}
.groups:nth-child(1) .fields:nth-child(2) {
  order: -1;                /*  default is 0  */
  background: lightgreen;
}
.groups:nth-child(3) .fields:nth-child(2),
.groups:nth-child(3) .fields:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="groups">
    <div class="fields">A 1</div>
    <div class="fields">A 2</div>
    <div class="fields">A 3</div>
    <div class="fields">A 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="groups">
    <div class="fields">B 1</div>
    <div class="fields">B 2</div>
    <div class="fields">B 3</div>
    <div class="fields">B 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="groups">
    <div class="fields">C 1</div>
    <div class="fields">C 2</div>
    <div class="fields">C 3</div>
    <div class="fields">C 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting...  Good direction, I somehow missed nth-child.  I'll play with this a bit more as this might just be what I need.   Thanks!

Comment: This will work great.  From the server side, I can set a style order, which will cause it to order based on data being fed to me by a rest service.

Comment: @Switch That sounds great you found it useful